# gnome-open execute shell script

Tags: shell-script, mime-types

Is there a way to execute shell scripts automatically using gnome-open? If I call

`gnome-open script.sh`

in the terminal, the script opens in the default text editor.

However the shell-script is executed directly by double-click from Nautilus.

Comment: Is script executable? As in `chmod +x script.sh`? Also I remember there used to be a setting in gnome to specify if it should execute scripts on open or edit them, so dig around for that :)

Comment: Yes the file is executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this execute the file:

```
./script.sh
```

or to get another terminal to execute it with:

```
gnome-terminal script.sh
```

`./` means look in the current directory, this is not usually required if prefixed by a command, which would would look in the current directory if no folders are specified.

Make sure it is executable with `chmod +x script.sh`.

Nautilus can do other things instead of just running it, look in the preferences under <kbd>Behaviour</kbd>:
[image]